# MapPoint lags with C#

Tags: c#, mappoint

I have included MapPoint control object into my C# form. Once I try to close the program mappoint seems to free for a bit and causes lag.

I tried setting `_mpMap.Saved = true;` but no luck

Answer (score 0):

MapPoint can pause during startup and shutdown due to cache issues, garbage collection, etc.

Make sure all of your MapPoint references are *clean*. As soon as you've finished with an object, clear the reference. For good measure run the garbage collection at a suitable point if possible (eg. After an object intensive batch job).

Are you working with MapPoint application or the control? Your question is ambiguous in this regard. Either way, you should consider a `using` statement.